# Not able to install appium using node.js

Tags: node.js, appium-android

Currently getting an error while trying to install the Appium using Node.js (Windows 10). For more information please refer to the below log file. Can you please help ?

```
12808 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.1 (node_modules\appium\node_modules\fsevents):
12809 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
12810 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
12810 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
12810 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
12810 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
12811 verbose stack Error: appium-chromedriver@4.10.1 install: `node install-npm.js`
12811 verbose stack Exit status 1
12811 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
12811 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
12811 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
12811 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
12811 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
12811 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
12812 verbose pkgid appium-chromedriver@4.10.1
12813 verbose cwd C:\Users\test
12814 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
12815 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "appium" "-unsafe-perm=true" "-allow-root"
12816 verbose node v10.15.0
12817 verbose npm  v6.4.1
12818 error code ELIFECYCLE
12819 error errno 1
12820 error appium-chromedriver@4.10.1 install: `node install-npm.js`
12820 error Exit status 1
**12821 error Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.10.1 install script.
12821 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
12822 verbose exit [ 1, true ]**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of Appium is depend on few things

1. Installation of Java and Setting Env Path

[Installation of Java](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/installation-of-android-studio/)

2. Installation of Node.js

   [Install Node.js](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/installation-of-node-js/)
3. Installation of APPIUM

[Appium Installation](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/installation-of-appium/)

Make sure that above three installations are as per the documentation and use open internet to do the downloading.

Answer (score 1):

sudo npm install --unsafe-per=true  -g appium

Regards,
Sukrant

Comment: Can you explain a bit why adding this flag would work?

Comment: Unsafe-perm flag is set to true to suppress the UID/GID (User Identifier/ Group Identifier) switching when running package scripts.The flag is explicitly set to false to prevent non-root user from installing packages.

If EACCESS error occurs while installing Electron, then running the installation through sudo and the unsafe-perm flag set to true will  install the package.


//Using unsafe-perm flag
sudo npm install electron --unsafe-perm=true
//